# How draw a progressBar with form horseshoe in android?

Tags: android, draw

Someone who can help me, I have to paint a horseshoe shaped progressBar and fill in the various progress with percentages in android, I can not find anything to do that way, please someone can help me, I give an example of what I need:

[image]